# Apache rewrite rule changing things that it shouldn't

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to set up an Apache server so that it redirects requests `https://example.edu/rdemos/(.*)` to a shiny server running on port 3838. Other web pages should go to the normal proxy server.

So I have the following directives in my `ssl.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/PP/(.*) https://example.com/PhysicsPlayground/$1

<Location /rdemos>
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/rdemos$ /rdemos/
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
  RewriteRule /rdemos/(.*) ws://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
  RewriteRule /rdemos/(.*) http://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3838/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3838/
  # Header edit Location ^/ /rdemos/                                                                                          
</Location>
```

This properly redirects files under `/rdemos`, so `https://example.com/rdemos/index.html` goes to the shiny server (port 3838) as expected.

However, other files get randomly redirected. So `https://example.com/PP/demo.html` gets routed to `https://example.com/rdemos/PhysicsPlayground/demo.html` (which does not exist).

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_fcgid/2.3.9 SVN/1.10.2 mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 mod_apreq2-20101207/2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to mix mod_alias, and mod_rewrite directives. Convert everything to mod_rewrite since you need to use that.

Redirecting rewrite rules should use `[R=301,L]`

I would not try to mix `ProxyPass` with rewrite rules with the `P` flag.  Just use rewrite rules.

It is more portable to to use `^/?` in rewrite rules so that they can work in `.htaccess` without modification.

You never need to specify `RewriteEngine on` more than once.

`ProxyPassReverse` should specify the subdirectory.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?PP/(.*) https://example.com/PhysicsPlayground/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?rdemos$ /rdemos/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
RewriteRule ^/?rdemos/(.*) ws://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
RewriteRule ^/?rdemos/(.*) http://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPassReverse /rdemos/ http://localhost:3838/
```